# iptables rejects vpn client by port

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, troubleshooting

Here is my iptables commands:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 109.123.74.85 --dport 27000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 188.170.80.4 --dport 27000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 27000 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -L
```

Which give me the following iptables rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  109.123.74.85        anywhere             tcp dpt:27000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  188.170.80.4         anywhere             tcp dpt:27000
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27000 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And I have simple HTTP server to test it out:

```
python3 -m http.server 27000
```

when I request it from a VPN client (ip 109.123.74.85): `curl myServerIP:27000/1.txt` it doesn't respond.

But when I turn off the VPN on the client and request `curl myServerIP:27000/1.txt` with client IP 188.170.80.4, it works fine.

Also, it's interesting that when I use port 8881 instead of 27000, it works pretty well for both VPN and none VPN clients.

So how to configure iptables to open port 27000 for specific IP address clients who are using VPN and block for everyone else?

## Update 1

To clarify response type: I get operation timeout when I request from VPN client:

```
curl myServerIP:27000/1.txt
curl: (7) Failed to connect to myServerIP port 27000: Operation timed out
```

## Update 2

When I described that with port 8881 it works fine, I meant that I used the following iptables in that case:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 109.123.74.85 --dport 8881 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 188.170.80.4 --dport 8881 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 8881 -j REJECT
```

## Update 3

This is how I check my client ip address: `curl ifconfig.me`

## Update 4

Damn, I realized that I got the same problem with VPN client requesting 27000 port even with empty iptables on the server. So I guess I should write to vpn provider support to figure out what's going on. Although requesting port 8881 works fine.

## Update 5 (final)

So I changed vpn provider and things are working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I guess you aren't iptables expert, so I'll try to help you quickly, but you should read [the iptables tutorial](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html) (it's a great doc) to understand details.

Save the example rule set into some file and the load it with `iptables-apply <path-to-file>` command. By default this command require the confirmation from user. If waiting timeout exceeded without confirmation from user, the ruleset will be rolled back.

Also, you should read the documentation for your linux distro to make the changes permanent, otherwise the results will be lost after system restart. It's a good idea to use the iptables-persistent package or similar.

General skeleton of rule set for your case:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.2 on Thu May 16 16:17:54 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:HTTP_IN - [0:0]

# allow already established and related connections
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# you can use multiple port numbers, separated with comma
# use the HTTP_IN chain for incoming packets to tcp/27000 port
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 27000 -j HTTP_IN

# allow local connections
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# allow the icmp packets. it can be improved.
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# this is the whitelist of ip addresses
-A HTTP_IN -s 109.123.74.85/32 -j ACCEPT
-A HTTP_IN -s 188.170.80.4/32 -j ACCEPT

# this rule should be last in the HTTP_IN chain
-A HTTP_IN -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

COMMIT
```

To add the new ip address to the whitelist better you edit the current ruleset file and load it with `iptables-restore` or `iptables-apply`. Also, you can use `iptables -I HTTP_IN --src <allowed-ip> -j ACCEPT` command.

Relating some details in your question.

> when I request it from a VPN client (ip 109.123.74.85): `curl myServerIP:27000/1.txt` it doesn't respond.

There is a difference between `not response` and `connection reset`. In first case you don't have any reply, in second - you receive the special packet (tcp with RST flag or some ICMP message). If you have no reply, there is issue in somewhere else - use the `tcpdump` to troubleshoot. If you have `ICMP port unreachable` reply - check ip address of your client, likely it's not same, than your expect. Also you can check the rule counters (better use `iptables-save -c` command to list the full rule set with counters).

> Also, it's interesting that when I use port 8881 instead of 27000, it works pretty well for both VPN and none VPN clients.

It's expected behaviour because in this case the packets don't pass your `ACCEPT`/`REJECT` rules and accepted by INPUT policy.

Most effective way to troubleshoot the connectivity between two hosts is using of `tcpdump` on both ends. Also, in the linux `tcpdump` captures incoming packets before `netfilter` (read as `iptables`) processing, but outgoing packets after firewall. If you see outgoing packets on one side, but you don't see they as incoming on the other side, then they are being dropped or lost somewhere between. You can use `traceroute` with `tcp`/`udp` packets to detect a problem host.

Comment: Hi @Anton I added updates 1,2,3 above in my question to clarify some details. Do you mean to use `tcpdump` on a client or on the server?

Comment: Better run the `tcpdump` on the server, where you're setting up the firewall.

Comment: `tcpdump` captures incoming packets before firewall processing. So, if you don't see the packets from remote side, then they are losing somewhere between client and server.

Comment: yeah that’s right, no packets detected on port 27000

Comment: Try to run `traceroute --tcp -p 27000 <dst>` on client host. Also, run `tcpdump` on the client host to sure, what packets are sent to outside.